# Difference between method calls

Tags: objective-c, syntax

I just want to know what the differences between these are:

1. `[MyClassInstance myMethodName];`
2. `MyClassInstance.myMethodName;`
3. `MyClassInstance->myMethodName;`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `MyClassInstance` is a variable of some object type...

1. That's the syntax for sending a message.
2. That's how to access a property. The compiler will look for the property declaration and insert a getter message here.
3. Using the arrow operator you can access ivars of the instance. No message is being sent.

Comment: No, the compiler will not look-up for a property declaration. It will look-up for a method declaration or property declaration – as it does for [] notation.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad When using dot notation the compiler's behavior differs from the message send case: It has to look for a property declaration to see if there's a special accessor defined for this property (as is often the case in Apple's frameworks for boolean properties, e.g. `isHidden`). This is not the case when using standard message syntax where any special accessor names are ignored.

Comment: It is true that a declared property can be parametrized including setter and getter names. So reading a property declaration and a method declaration slightly differs. But this is done for both syntaxes. If the getter has a getter-attribute, the usual message syntax respects this, too. Therefore "That's [using the dot notation] how to access a property" is not true. Both syntaxes are how messages are sent, independently of the way the method is declared and independently of the way, the message is constructed.

Answer (score 1):

```
[MyClassInstance myMethodName];
```

is Called Message Passing and

```
MyClassInstance.myMethodName;
```

is called accessing by dot operator as done in other languages.
Both are Techniques to access attributes and methods , but Message Passing is more modern approach and more realistic.Because Objective-C makes code standards Easy to understand , the message passing technique is like real world command to do some work. for example 
[Car Drive]
[Car Turn] 
etc.While dot notation has resemblance to more programing world  rather than real world.Objective-C dot notation is a syntactic sugar that is translated to normal message passing, so under the hood changes nothing and makes no difference at runtime. Dot notation it is absolutely not faster than message passing.

**Dot notation pros and cons**

**pros**

readability : dot notation is easier to read than nested brackets massages passing
It simplifies interaction with Attributes and Properties: using dot notation for properties and message notation for methods you can achieve separation of state and behavior at the synthax level
It is possible to use compound assignment operator (1).
using the @property and dot notation the compiler do a lot of work for you, it can generate code for good Memory Management when getting and setting the property; this is why dot notation is suggested by Apple itself official guides.

**cons**

Dot notation is allowed only for access to a declared @property
Since Objective-C is a layer above standard C(language extension), the dot notation doesn’t really make clear if the accessed entity is a an object or a struct. Often, it looks like you are accessing properties of a struct.
calling a method with the dot notation you lose named parameters readability advantages
when mixed message notation and dot notation seems like you are coding in two different languages

Answer (score -3):

Both are same. It's a matter of choice and readability.

Comment: It's not same, You can not call class methods using `.` operator.

Comment: Are you sure? because i heard somewhere it might be difference between those.

Comment: Yes i try, and now in iOS 8 most of the methods are deprecated and added new one like this. Removed -[CLLocation description] and Added CLLocation.description. if both are same then no need to deprecated Right ?

Comment: @JaydeepPatoliya You are talking about Swift language, it is differnet

Comment: @Kampai: Yes, you can call class methods with dot notation: `NSString.string` works just fine. You _shouldn't_, but you can.